# Core Data in Swift: Only saving last object in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, core-data

I'm trying to save multiple objects in Core Data to the IPodSongs entity in a `for` loop, namely the title of the song currently in the `for song in result{}` loop. But my code only saves the very last song in the loop, and just keeps overwriting the same object. Instead of overwriting the same object, I need to create a new object each time. What am I doing wrong?

```
func fetchiPodSongsOnSignup() {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var newSong = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("IPodSongs", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "IPodSongs")

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)


        let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

        let result = query.collections as! [MPMediaItemCollection]

        for song in result {

            for song in song.items as! [MPMediaItem] {

                newSong.setValue("\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))", forKey: "title")

                println(newSong)

                context.save(nil)

            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, you create one object `var newSong = ....` and then overwrite its properties in each loop iteration. Isn't the solution obvious?

Comment: Please do not pass `nil` in the save.  Pass in an error pointer and check for the error.  ALWAYS!

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to create a request to save new objects to Core Data. What you did wrong was create a single managed object, inserted it and then changeded it through the loop instead of creating a new object for each song.

**This should work:**

```
func fetchiPodSongsOnSignup() {

    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!


    let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

    let result = query.collections as! [MPMediaItemCollection]

    for song in result {

        for song in song.items as! [MPMediaItem] {

            var newSong = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("IPodSongs", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

            newSong.setValue("\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))", forKey: "title")

            println(newSong)


        }
    }
    if context.save(&errorPointer == false {
        printlin("Error received while saving")
    }

}
```

Also put `if context.save(&errorPointer == false {printlin("Error received while saving")}` at the very end.

Comment: Certainly you mean putting `if context.save(&errorPointer == false {printlin("Error received)}` at the end right? :)

Comment: Yea sure, but it seems like the inquirer doesn't care if there's an error at saving the context...

Comment: or is uneducated.  Perfect opportunity to educate them that the error is vital.  Examples passing `nil` cause that ignorance of its value.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm new to Swift (only a month into programming in general) so I appreciate your help. There's a parenthesis missing from the last `if context.save{}` method. If I put it right after `false`, I get an unresolved identifier `errorPointer`.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Can I get confirmation on this `errorPointer`? I'm still getting an error with the missing parenthesis.

Comment: You need to define it as `var errorPointer: NSError? = nil` before you can pass it into a variable.  This is just like you would do in Objective-C. Note you are passing `nil` in a couple of places for `error:`

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra where does the missing parenthesis go? After `&errorPointer`? I don't get an error there but it seems as if `== false` should be within it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this , this will work ....

Insert in for loop and save in outside loop ...

```
func fetchiPodSongsOnSignup() {

var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!


let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

let result = query.collections as! [MPMediaItemCollection]

for song in result {

    for song in song.items as! [MPMediaItem] {

        var newSong = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("IPodSongs", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        newSong.setValue("\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))", forKey: "title")

        context.insert(newSong)

    }
}
context.save(nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same inserted object in all iterations :

```
for song in song.items as! [MPMediaItem] {
      newSong.setValue("\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))", forKey: "title")
```

You are indeed changing the song's object value but you use the same instance which in turn is the same entity in the core db.

You need to use a new instance for every new song:

```
 var newSong = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("IPodSongs", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
 newSong.setValue("\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))", forKey: "title")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you most probably! Try it!

```
for song in result {

        for song in song.items as! [MPMediaItem] {
            var newSong = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("IPodSongs", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
            newSong.setValue("\(song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle))", forKey: "title")

            println(newSong)

            context.save(nil)

        }
    }
```