# How to create entities in core data with a for in loop?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

hope you guys are doing well. I have 2 entities in my DB: one is House with an attribute for total number of floors and the second is Floors with an attribute floor number (the num of floors in the house). There is a 1 to many rel. between Floors and Rooms. If i insert 3 floors, i need 3 separate instances of Floors so I can carry on assigning rooms for each floor.
What I am struggling with is how do I use a for in loop to create the correct number of Floors entities so i can assign for each of them the number of rooms(Room being a different entity with different attributes). Please see my attempt below and if you could try and help me with this.

```
class SetNumberOfFloorsVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Properties

@IBOutlet private weak var numberOfFloorsTxt: UITextField!

private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

private var floorNumberValue: Int16 {
    get {
        return Int16 (numberOfFloorsTxt.text!)!
    }
}

//MARK: - Actions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



@IBAction private func setTheNumberOfFloors(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let correctType = floorNumberValue as? Int16 { // ignore the warning because I need to check if the value is for sure Int16.
        let house = House(context: managedObjectContext)
        house.numberOfFloors = correctType
        print("\(house.numberOfFloors)")

        let floor = Floors(context: managedObjectContext)
        for i in 0...house.numberOfFloors {
            floor.floorNumber = Int16(i)
            print("\(floor.floorNumber)")
        }
    } else {
        let screenAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Incorrect value. Only single or double digit numbers please!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        screenAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(screenAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}


// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "assign number of rooms": if let vc = segue.destination as? SetNumberOfRoomsPerFloor {
            vc.floorValue = floorNumberValue
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're finding that only a singe `Floors` object is being created? This sort of question is fairy common when people start working with CoreData! Try this thread and see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393441/core-data-in-swift-only-saving-last-object-in-a-for-loop

Comment: yes that helped me. Thank you very much kind sir.